# Multiple php versions, can't connect with mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

following http://kb.sp.parallels.com/en/118378 i succesfully installed php 5.4.38 and 5.5.21 to a centos 6.6 plesk server running on php 5.3

After transfering a joomla site on this server i get:

```
Error displaying the error page: Application Instantiation Error: Could not connect to MySQL.
```

By changing $dbtype from mysqli to mysql in joomla's configuration.php i got it working but this is not what i want

in addition i have more custom web sites that i transfered which use mysqli and all of them return:

```
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or director
```

i checked unix_socket, it is the default but i saved it in the php.ini 's of php 5.4 and 5.5 anyways `mysqli.default_socket = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock`still nothing

is it that php-mysqli is not istalled for the additional versions of php? 
if that is the case how can i yum install modules on these paraller php instances?

phpinfo for mysqli for default Centos 5.3.3 is

- MysqlI Support    enabled
- Client API library version    5.1.73
- Active Persistent Links   0
- Inactive Persistent Links     0
- Active Links  0
- Client API header version     5.1.73
- MYSQLI_SOCKET     /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

phpinfo for mysqli for custom installed 5.4 is

- MysqlI Support    enabled
- Client API library version    mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: bf************************8c5c77 $
- Active Persistent Links   0
- Inactive Persistent Links     0
- Active Links  0

Comment: Have you checked the php.ini config file for each installation to make sure that mysqli is enabled? Try running `php_info()` on each installation to see.

Comment: Can i know why you are using multiple versions ?????

Comment: - yes it seems enabled but comparing the phpinfo of 5.5 and 5.3 i see that at 5.3 there are 2 more lines
"Client API header version  5.1.73
MYSQLI_SOCKET  /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock"
which are missing from 5.5 and 5.4

Comment: I am using multiple versions because centos comes with 5.3.3 and Joomla needs 5.3.10 and above.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and I resolve changing "localhost" with 127.0.0.1